# Google AdSense in my website

Tags: google-adsense

If I am a resident of the United States and I wish to run Google AdSense in my website, how many months old should my website be?

Comment: You need to own the site for at-least 6 months. Make sure it is generating some healthy traffic.

Comment: They only require a history of six months for a few countries outside the U.S., see: [Eligibility to participate in AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724?hl=en&ref_topic=1319756)